# How to change backGround Image from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have two form and i want to change backGround of first form from 2nd form. i have already choose a backGround image for form1 and button1 in form2, but nothing happens. thanx in advance (Windows Form)
1st form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

2nd Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            frm1.BackgroundImage = button1.BackgroundImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second form, add a private member that will hold a reference to the first form:

```
private Form _form1 = null;
```

Then in the constructor for Form2, allow that reference to be passed in:

```
public Form2(Form form1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _form1 = form1;
}
```

Now, in that button click handler, you can:

```
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form1.BackgroundImage = button1.BackgroundImage;
}
```

An alternative approach would be to add a method to Form1 that receives the image to be set as background.  Assume the same `_form1` reference exists in Form2, you add this to Form1:

```
public void ChangeBGImage(Image bgImage)
{
    this.BackgroundImage = bgImage;
}
```

And from Form2, you call it:

```
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form1.ChangeBGImage(button1.BackgroundImage);
}
```

Comment: what sholud i send as my argument to Form2 frm2 = new Form2();?

Comment: I assume you create Form2 _in_ Form1, correct?  If so:  `Form 2 frm2 = new Form2(this);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't access to the `form1` from `form2` to change it. If you want to change something in `form1` you shouldn't create new instance of `Form1`. You should get the instance in the constructor.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm1; 
    public Form2(Form1 frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.frm1 = frm1; 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.BackgroundImage = button1.BackgroundImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

FOrm1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

            //check if button1 clicked and then change the background
            if(frm2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                  this.BackgroundImage = frm2.GetBackImage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            //frm1.BackgroundImage = button1.BackgroundImage;
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        }

       public Image GetBackImage()
       {
           return this.button1.BackgroundImage;
       }
    }
}
```